# Laravel 5.4 update method

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to update the record in the database. This is a specific element that is an element of another. Here is my code, it doesnt work :/

web.php :

```
 Route::patch('/projects/{projectID}/{id}', 'ProjectsController@update');
```

Controller:

```
public function update($projectId, $id, CreateProjectRequest $request)
    {
        $page = Page::findOrFail($id);
        $page->update([
           'name' => $request->name,
       ]);

       return redirect('/projects/' . $projectId);
    }
```

HTML:

`{!! Form::model($page, ['method'=>'PATCH', 'action' =>` `['ProjectsController@update', $project->id, $page->id]]) !!}`

```
  {!! Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'blue-inp']) !!}

 {!! Form::submit('Save changes',['class'=>'btn btn-save-blue']) !!}

 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Switch `CreateProjectRequest` for just `Request` in your update function

Comment: Thanks ! This helps solve my problem !

Comment: Your welcome I will make it an answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the class type-hint `CreateProjectRequest` for just `Request` in your controllers update method.

The variables passed from the form input fields can then be accessed like this:

```
$name = $request->input('name');
```

More on the topic: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the controller method, assuming the `CreateProjectRequest` handled all the necessary validation and it's inputs match the inputs you want to update
Edit: I prefer to validate everything with formrequests with rules and by the time it reaches the controller, it just calls services or does stuff.
As far as naming conventions, you may not need to send the $id in the url parameter and send it within the body, in order to avoid using Request in the formrequest to validate if it exists in the database

```
public function update($projectId, $id, CreateProjectRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->validated();
    Page::findOrFail($id)->update($data);

    return redirect('/projects/' . $projectId);
}
```